# Google Optimize track clicks

Tags: google-optimize

Is there a way to setup Google Optimize A/B test to track clicks on an element? I saw a demo video where they used a sign-up button variations, yet, I'm not able to find how to create such objective. I create a custom one but have no idea how to specify the element which clicks I wish to track. All I'm trying to do is to test if the clicks will increase/decrease based on the button position (left/right). Totally confused.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only can create objetives with events sended to GA (with their category, action, label...)
For example, you can send events to GA throught GTM.

Then you can specify the category/action/label in your Optimize objetive.

You can find more information about objetives here: https://support.google.com/optimize/answer/7018998?hl=en&ref_topic=6197696